# Inject component with Angular

Tags: angular

In my angular application, I have a component in the root element that is always there. For example:

```
<foo></foo>
```

This component has a "show" method that I can use to display the component. I'd like to be able to get a reference to this component from any component of my project to be able to show the "foo" component from everywhere. I know that I could use a service to do that, but I would prefer being able to inject a reference to this component into other ones. Something like:

```
export class MyComponent {
   constructor(private _foo: FooComponent) {}
}
```

Is it possible to do something like that with Angular?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't inject a component in like a service. A component is not injectable.

You can use @ViewChild to get a reference to that component. But only from any component that contains that component.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to set some setup information for the component and it is *not* a child component (nested within the parent component with its selector), then your next best option is a service.

You can build a service and inject it into both components. In one component, you can set any initialization and set up values. In the other component, you can read those values as you set up the component.

If you only need to hide or show the component, another option you can consider is to have two different components, one with the `<foo></foo>` and the other without the `<foo>`. Then you can route other components to the page containing the `<foo>` or not containing the `<foo>` instead of turning it on and off.

Here is a picture of what I mean. In my case `<foo>` is my menu component.

[image]

My app Component has a router outlet that is the entire page. I route anything there that I don't want to have the menu (such as the login page.)

My shell component has the menu and a router outlet. I route anything there that I do want to display the menu.

Comment: Well, it's actually not that simple. The thing is that I need a reference to the component because I need to call the "show" method and pass argument to leverage the way it's shown, it's not just a show/hide.